# How can I retrieve only WooCommerce products with specific IDs through a query?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, product, advanced-custom-fields

I am making a custom template for an e-commerce website. I am creating a block to display multiple products. This list of product can be sorted in various ways (ex: random). To divide the work I made a function that generates a list of IDs that need to be displayed.

I created a function to display the product with this list of IDs, but it doesn't use the IDs for an obscure reason :/ (it returns products sorted by date):

```
function displayProducts($product_ids)
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post__in' => $product_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => count($product_ids),
    );

    $products_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($products_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($products_query->have_posts()) {
            $products_query->the_post();
            $product = wc_get_product();

            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product_title = get_the_title();
            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($product_id);
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full');
            $categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
            $artists = wc_get_product_terms($product_id, 'artiste');

            $parts = explode(' &#8211; ', $product_title, 2);
            $title = isset($parts[0]) ? $parts[0] : '';

            echo '
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="' . get_permalink($product_id) . '">
                        <img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" href="' . get_permalink($product_id) . '" alt="' . $product_id . '" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="' . get_permalink($product_id) . '">
                            <h3>' . esc_html($title) . $product_id . '</h3>
                        </a>';

            if ($artists && !empty($artists)) {
                $artist = $artists[0];
                echo '<p>par <a href="' . get_term_link($artist) . '">' . esc_html($artist->name) . '</a></p>';
            }

            if ($categories && !is_wp_error($categories)) {
                $category_links = array();
                echo '<div class="categories">';
                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $category_links[] = '<a class="category" href="' . get_term_link($category) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
                }
                echo implode(', ', $category_links);
                echo '</div>';
            }

            echo '
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$product_ids` an array of post IDs?

Answer (score 0):

So i find out after 1 day:

> ```
> $args = array(
>     'post_type' => 'product',
>     'post__in' => $product_ids,
>     'posts_per_page' => count($product_ids),
>     'orderby' => 'post__in' // Add this line to maintain order of IDs
> );
> ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).